# How can I configure Adobe Bridge so that it uses MS Paint to edit images?

Tags: adobe-bridge

How can I configure Adobe Bridge so that it uses MS Paint to edit images? It uses Photoshop by default on my computer (Win10):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I configure Adobe Bridge so that it uses MS Paint to edit images?

As per the help documentation:

> **Change file type associations**
>
> Selecting the application to open a specific file type affects only
> those files that you open using Adobe Bridge and overrides operating
> system settings.
>
> - Choose Edit > Preferences (Windows) or Adobe Bridge > Preferences (Mac OS), and click File Type Associations.
> - Click the name of the application (or None) and click Browse to locate the application to use.
> - To reset the file type associations to their default settings, click Reset To Default Associations.
> - To hide any file types that don’t have associated applications, select Hide Undefined File Associations.

Source: [How to view & manage files in Adobe Bridge](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/bridge/using/view-files-bridge.html)